# Applying script to multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I have a script with a number of steps involved which I need to apply to 20-30 dataframes  and produce separate dataframes each named differently at the end. 
I've had a look through doing it with functions and/or lists but havent been able to find a way yet.

This is the script to perform the analysis on one file

```
 ####time series data
  C_A <- read.csv(file=file.choose(), skip = 8)
C_A <- C_A %>%
  mutate('10_sec_avg' = rollmean(Velocity, 10, align="right", na.pad=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE))


###C_A$Distance <- cumsum(C_A$Speed.m.s*.1) ### multiply the speed times the seconds to get a distance and then sum the rows to get a total distance
C_A$DistCov <- ave(C_A$Odometer, FUN = function(x ) c(0, diff(x))) ##measures the change in total distance
##C_A$Distance_raw <- C_A$Velocity
C_A$Change_distance_1min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 601, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 1 minute periods
C_A$Change_distance_2min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 1201, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 2 minute periods
C_A$Change_distance_3min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 1801, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 3 minute periods
C_A$Change_distance_4min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 2401, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 4 minute periods
C_A$Change_distance_5min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 3001, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 5 minute periods
C_A$Change_distance_6min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 3601, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 6 minute periods
C_A$Change_distance_7min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 4201, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 7 minute periods
C_A$Change_distance_8min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 4801, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 8 minute periods
C_A$Change_distance_9min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 5401, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 9 minute periods
C_A$Change_distance_10min <- rollsumr(C_A$DistCov, 6001, fill = 0) ###rolling sum of distance over 10 10 minute periods

C_A$Min10_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 600)) ### break in to 10 minute chuncks
C_A$Min1_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 60)) ### break into 1 minute chunks
C_A$Min2_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 120)) ### break into 2 minute chunks
C_A$Min3_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 180)) ### break into 3 minute chunks
C_A$Min4_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 240)) ### break into 4 minute chunks
C_A$Min5_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 3000)) ### break into 5 minute chunks
C_A$Min6_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 360)) ### break into 6 minute chunks
C_A$Min7_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 420)) ### break into 7 minute chunks
C_A$Min8_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 480)) ### break into 8 minute chunks
C_A$Min9_Cat <- cut(C_A$Seconds, breaks = seq(-1, 7520, by = 540)) ### break into 9 minute chunks



C_A3 <- C_A %>% group_by(Min1_Cat,Min2_Cat, Min3_Cat, Min4_Cat, Min5_Cat, Min6_Cat, Min7_Cat, Min8_Cat, Min9_Cat, Min10_Cat) %>%
  summarize(avgDistCov_1min = mean(Change_distance_1min, na.rm=T),
            avgDistCov_2min = mean(Change_distance_2min, na.rm=T),
            avgDistCov_3min = mean(Change_distance_3min, na.rm=T),
            avgDistCov_4min = mean(Change_distance_4min, na.rm=T),
            avgDistCov_5min = mean(Change_distance_5min, na.rm=T),
            avgDistCov_6min = mean(Change_distance_6min, na.rm=T),
            avgDistCov_7min = mean(Change_distance_7min, na.rm=T),
            avgDistCov_8min = mean(Change_distance_8min, na.rm=T),
            avgDistCov_9min = mean(Change_distance_9min, na.rm=T),
            avgDistCov_10min = mean(Change_distance_10min, na.rm=T))


Player_data <- data.frame(Time = c("Min_1","Min_2","Min_3","Min_4","Min_5","Min_6","Min_7","Min_8","Min_9","Min_10"), 
                          Max.Distance = c(max(C_A3$avgDistCov_1min),max(C_A3$avgDistCov_2min),max(C_A3$avgDistCov_3min),max(C_A3$avgDistCov_4min),
                                           max(C_A3$avgDistCov_5min),max(C_A3$avgDistCov_6min),max(C_A3$avgDistCov_7min),max(C_A3$avgDistCov_8min),
                                           max(C_A3$avgDistCov_9min),max(C_A3$avgDistCov_10min)))
min <- c(1:10)
Player_data$M_min <- Player_data$Max.Distance/min
```

It takes the data which was recorded with a new datapoint every 1 millisecond and identifies the highest distance then across different time spans within which are then produced in the Player_data dataframe.

Can this be automated for multiple files which would all be stored together?

Thanks

Comment: you can put your data.frames in a list and use lapply

Comment: It would seem that you want to read 20-30 files and apply the procedure described above. Consider creating a vector of files (you can use `list.files()`). Consider making your procedure into a function (basically you need to just wrap everything into `myFun <- function(x) {}` and switch `file.choose()` to `x`). Applying this function to your list of filenames should be easy using `lapply` as @Cath mentioned.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks @RomanLuštrik & Cath